# Point2D class objects

Tags: c++, inheritance

This is what I need to do: Add a new data member, string color to your Point2D class and a new getter and setter function for color. Create a Point2D object and set its color. Then create a Point3D color and try to set its color. Is this setColor behavior available for a Point3D class? Why or why not?

This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class Point2D
{
    friend class SPALops;
    protected:
        float x;
        float y;

    protected:  
        float getX(){
            return x;
        };
        float getY(){
            return y;
        };
        void setX(float xc){
            x = xc;
        };
        void setY(float yc){
            y = yc;
        };

        Point2D(int xcoord, int ycoord){
            x = xcoord;
            y = ycoord;
        };
};


class Point2D : Point2D
{
    friend class SPALops;
        public:

        Point2D(int x, int y) : Point2D(x,y){}

        Point2D() : Point2D(0,0){}

    float getX(){
        return this->Point2D::getX();
    };

    float getY(){
        return this->Point2D::getY();
    };

    void setX(float x){
        this->Point2D::setX(x);
    };

    void setY(float y){
        this->Point2D::setY(y);
    };



};


class RectangleImplementation{
    friend class SPALops;
    protected:
        Point2D ll;
        Point2D ur;

        RectangleImplementation(float llx, float lly, float urx, float ury){
            ll.setX(llx); ll.setY(lly);
            ur.setX(urx); ur.setY(ury);
        }

        void setLLx(float x){
            ll.setX(x);
        };
        void setLLy(float y){
            ll.setY(y);
        };
        void setURx(float x){
            ur.setX(x);
        };
        void setURy(float y){
            ur.setY(y);
        };
        float getLLx(){
            return ll.getX();
        };
        float getLLy(){
            return ll.getY();
        };
        float getURx(){
            return ur.getX();
        };
        float getURy(){
            return ur.getY();
        };

        vector<vector<float> > getPointList(){
            vector<vector<float> > v(4);
            vector<float> llv(2); llv[0] = ll.getX(); llv[1] = ll.getY();
            v[0] = llv;
            vector<float> luv(2); luv[0] = ll.getX(); luv[1] = ur.getY();
            v[1] = luv;
            vector<float> ruv(2); ruv[0] = ur.getX(); ruv[1] = ur.getY();
            v[2] = ruv;
            vector<float> rlv(2); rlv[0] = ur.getX(); rlv[1] = ll.getY();
            v[3] = rlv;      
            return v;    
        };

        void printPointList(){
            vector<vector<float>> v = this->getPointList();
            cout << "ll = " << v[0][0] << " , " << v[0][1] << endl;
            cout << "lu = " << v[1][0] << " , " << v[1][1] << endl;
            cout << "ru = " << v[2][0] << " , " << v[2][1] << endl;
            cout << "rl = " << v[3][0] << " , " << v[3][1] << endl;
        };

};

class Rectangle : RectangleImplementation{
    friend class SPALops;
    public:

    Rectangle(Point2D &p, Point2D &q) : RectangleImplementation(p.getX(), p.getY(), q.getX(), q.getY()){};
    Rectangle(float llx, float lly, float urx, float ury): RectangleImplementation(llx,lly,urx,ury){};

    float getLLx(){
        return this->RectangleImplementation::getLLx();
    };
    float getLLy(){
        return this->RectangleImplementation::getLLy();
    };
    float getURx(){
        return this->RectangleImplementation::getURx();  
    };
    float getURy(){
        return this->RectangleImplementation::getURy();
    };

    void setLLx(float x){
        this->RectangleImplementation::setLLx(x);
    };
    void setLLy(float y){
        this->RectangleImplementation::setLLy(y);
    };
    void setURx(float x){
        this->RectangleImplementation::setURx(x);
    };
    void setURy(float y){
        this->RectangleImplementation::setURx(y);
    };

    void printPointList(){
        cout << "In rectangle: " << endl;
        cout << "ll = " << ll.getX() << " , " << this->RectangleImplementation::getLLy() << endl;
        cout << "ru = " << this->getURx() << " , " << this->RectangleImplementation::getURy() << endl;
    };
};


class SPALops{
public:
static bool touches(Rectangle &r, Point2D &p){
        vector<vector<float> > v = r.RectangleImplementation::getPointList();
        if((v[0][0] == p.getX() and v[0][1] == p.getY()) or
           (v[1][0] == p.getX() and v[1][1] == p.getY()) or
           (v[2][0] == p.getX() and v[2][1] == p.getY()) or
           (v[3][0] == p.getX() and v[3][1] == p.getY()))
        {
          return true;
        }
        else
        {
          return false;
        }

    };
};

int main(){
    Point2D p(10,10);
    Point2D q(15,15);
    Point2D s(20,20);
    Point2D t(10,12);

    Rectangle r(p,q);

    r.printPointList();

    cout << "Do rectangle 'r' and point 'p' touch = " << SPALops::touches(r,p) << endl;
    cout << "Do rectangle 'r' and point 's' touch = " << SPALops::touches(r,s) << endl;
    cout << "Do rectangle 'r' and point 't' touch = " << SPALops::touches(r,t) << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

It seems I have many errors that stop me from running succesfully. I would appreciate if I get any feedback.

Comment: `class Point2D : Point2D` is this a typo?

Comment: use a compiler. it will give you feedback in terms of error messages. Seriously, if you have compiler error and you need help to fix them you should tell us what are the errors

Comment: Self inheritance, cool inbreeding.  You probably want a `Point3D` class that inherits from `Point2D`, like the problem statement.

Comment: look up the concept of the "Forward Declaration". You need one so that the classes defined above `SPALops` can know that `SPALops` exists.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some issues I found in your post:
1) Duplicate classes.
You have a `Point2D` class first, then a 2nd `Point2D` class.
Maybe you wanted the 2nd class to be `Point3D`.

2) Public Inheritance.
Your `class Point2D: Point2D` is *private* inheritance.
You may want to use *public* inheritance:
`class Point3D : public Point2D`

3) The `this->` notation not needed.
When accessing members or functions of the class, access them directly:

```
int getX() const
{ return x; }
```

4) Don't duplicate parent functions.
No need to have parent functions repeated in the child class.  For example, the child class doesn't need a `getX` method.  This is what inheritance is for -- so you **don't** need to duplicate methods.

5) Child constructor calls parent constructor.
Your constructor should look something like this:

```
Point3D(int new_x, int new_y, int new_z)
 : Point2D(new_x, new_y),
   z(new_z)
{ ; }
```

Too many other errors to discuss in one post.  The above should get you started and give you patterns to apply to other classes.